How to use a player's backstory without ignoring the other players?
I have a player with a really good backstory.  It includes a character who could honestly be one of, if not the main, BBEG of our campaign. I’m scared that if I use their backstory, I might end up ignoring the other players' backstories.
It’s D&D 5e, we haven’t actually started, but the campaign is planned to go on for a while, there’s me - the DM, and 5 players. The campaign is about them trying to take down a criminal organisation made up of 6 different factions, each one led by a different one of the 6 original fullcasting classes (wizard, sorcerer, warlock, cleric, druid, bard) each one more powerful than the last (think Pokémon gym style where in order to beat each leader, you need to beat the one before them). I’m thinking after they defeat the last leader, maybe this character fills the power vacuum. Similar to Pokémon, this criminal gang isn’t really the main problem. They are necessary for the story to progress but the player's backstory has an old mentor who betrayed him, and is presumed dead.  I want him to come back as an undead warlock (like he did die but was raised by his patron) leading a cult that is pulling the strings on the first group.
I’m worried it will put all the focus on this player and ignore the others. Any advice?

This is a question about GMing technique and style, and should be answerable by a GM with experience of running for players with different levels of backstory detail. Knowing the specifics of the campaign's setting and premise would be useful for writing examples, but isn't strictly necessary for answering the question. Accordingly, I'm voting to reopen the question.

Should this be tagged with 5e or system-agnostic?

@TreeSpawned I don't see anything system specific in this question

@Caleth other than this in paragraph 2... "It’s D&D 5e, we haven’t actually started, but the campaign is planned to go on for a while, there’s me - the DM, and 5 players."

@KorvinStarmast OP's campaign is using D&D 5e, but nothing in the question is specific to that

Do the other players have back stories at all?

Have you asked the other players if it is a problem for them that the story largely revolves around this? Some players don't mind a lack of involvement in the backstory, so long as they get equal table time in the now.

This is doable, but don't get ahead of yourself

I’m thinking after they defeat the last leader, maybe this character
fills the power vacuum.

That initiative needs to come from the player, and this addition to the NPCs in your world is best done in collaboration with the player(s).  If they want to roll with that, great, but be patient and see if that same idea comes from them during the course of play.
Depending on how you two collaborate, what you will have enabled is for the player to contribute to world building in your game world. (I have often contributed to world building for my DMs in the past, but that was intentional and this doesn't so far seem to be the player's intent).
If what you are planning is "what this NPC does after the campaign ends and we play something else" then you have been saved a lot of work.
But first, a caveat: Play and Find Out.
It is far more important for the players to play in the world that you are DMing, and to make their own decisions and choices, than for you - in Author Mode - to have already planned out an ultimate arc for one (or all) of the players, and/or how their backstory folds into your campaign world.
You aren't writing a novel, you are DMing a D&D 5e game. How much the other players are interested in bits of their backstory being folded into the game world, will only come to light if you engage with them and discuss it.  Their view on that may change as play progresses.  They may wish to contribute more, or less.
I have seen this done very well.
Our group of four players have done three complete campaigns, and are on campaign number four, where the DM explicitly solicits from us backstories that he can find ways to fold into the campaign. It's been very successful, but here's the key bit: it is done with player consent1.
He asks, we provide.
I love writing back stories, but some players like to get the feel for their character (and their history) before figuring out some of the back story details.  Both approaches can work.
From Campaign 1, the Bard (me) has become the leader of a merchant shipping company that support via covert operations a revolt by the goblins on an island - an island being occupied by a variation of Gith. The Paladin got elected president of a major guild and has created a seminary for one of the deities in the world.  The Warlock is the enforcer for a Patron (a demigod of death), and the Sorcerer is making a bid for the crown of the Southern kingdom (with a lot of help from the Bard, who is politically connected with two different royal families in two other kingdoms).
The pirate whom my bard eventually defeated was the BBEG for an extended arc and came from my background (right out of the PHB, Sailor) and from the backstory I wrote to capture the "pirates killed my shipmates, I am the only survivor" bit.
As a point of comparison: one of the background characters from our collective back stories in Campaign 2 ended up becoming an adversary to the party, which caught all four of us by surprise. He was originally created by me during our brainstorming sessions before Campaign 2, and began as our mentor, initially...and we discovered later that he was manipulating us for his own purposes, some of them nefarious! (We dealt with his betrayal, of course).
All of the Campaign 1 NPC activity has been referred to in campaigns 2 and 3, and was set up by a variety of adventures, quests, and RP during a 1-20 level campaign.  (Campaigns 2 and 3 went from 3 - 17 and 3 - 18 respectively).
The major quests in the campaign were woven together by the DM: Warlock finds out who his parents are, Halfling resolves issues with estranged wife (it was bloody), Bard finds the pirate who killed her shipmates and got her revenge, and the Sorcerer removed a usurper from the line of succession to the Southern throne. (We did each story line as a team).
Each PC has a backstory element woven into the campaign by the DM.
If your other players don't want to go into the detail of the backstory just now, don't worry about it.  As you play each session and they overcome your quest progression, they can (if they get invested in the world) offer up backstory bits as they become more familiar with their characters through play.  Solicit their input on that from time to time and see where it goes.
You may end up getting 'bonus' world building bits from them.
Our Warlock player (from Campaign 1) took half a dozen sessions in Campaign 2 to iron out the backstory bits to his satisfaction, and then the DM folded that in.
What if the other players don't want to?
Nothing you can do about that other than encourage them during play.  If they don't bite on the bait, they don't bite.  You already have your adventure theme (the Pokemon mechanic) so once the final boss has been defeated (hopefully) you can find out if they want to go on more adventures, or, retire these characters and play others.
And you can position NPCs from their backstories into the world, where they fit.
In other words, a lot of the answers to your question come as a result of play.  You don't need to get all of what you are looking for up front.
What I have seen work in play is for the DM to let some of the back stories emerge during play, rather than expecting all of your players to front load them as your one player has.  Each player has a different approach to back stories, and a different desire for character development.
Play And Find Out.
Let your players surprise you.  Let more of their backstories trickle down to you from them, organically.
It has worked at our table for three campaigns, and it's already blossoming in campaign number four as we investigate various goings on in the Northern Forests...

1 The DM is Benjamin T Hall (RPGSE member) but he doesn't contribute here very much these days.  He notes the following in a comment:

A key is knowing your setting and working with the players to tune their back stories with the understanding that they'll be used and that they're shared property between the DM and the player

That is how it works at our table.  It is a successful approach.

As the DM referenced, I fully support what's written here. A key is knowing your setting and working with the players to tune their back stories with the understanding that they'll be used and that they're shared property between the DM and the player.

@BenjaminTHall Thank you for dropping by, looking forward to next session.

Are you assuming that "this character" in the quote from the OP refers to the player character rather than the character in the PC's backstory?  I was assuming it referred to the latter.

Yes, I am, I may need to revisit that as, since "ignore the other backstories" piece is what got me to answer in the first place.  Hmmm. Thanks for the tip.

If you want your campaign to have people for the other PCs to interact with, you need to put more people in your campaign.
Not people who are part of other PCs' backgrounds, or people who care about other PCs. Just... people. People who want things and take actions in pursuit of their wants.
Then, you just need to sit on the reveal of... okay, I'm going to call the backstabbing presumed-dead warlich "Merasmus" because a name is easier. Then you just need to sit on the reveal of Merasmus until the time comes to confront the man behind the curtain, as it were. At this point, all your other PCs will have the entire six-arms-of-a-criminal-organization campaign in addition to the backstory they came to the table with, and if they fostered a relationship with any of the people you put into the campaign, then they have at least as rich a tie as the PC who put Merasmus in their backstory.
Making People
You're not making people for the PCs to like. You're making people, and the PCs can treat them how they want. You might make a handful of people in the six arms of a criminal organization who you intend to be sympathetic, but it's up to the PCs who they wind up with sympathy for. These people are using magic to do crimes, they don't have to be admirable, and they don't have to be intricate or complex. I've had good luck focusing on three things:

what they think of what their faction's doing
what they think about what they're doing right now
what they're like off the clock

Or reverse the last two if the PCs run into them when they're not on faction business.
But you're not just making the six arms of a criminal organization. There's all those people just out there getting crimed on. What do they want, more than just not getting crimed on? Are there legitimate authorities, vigilante bands, private securitors, guilds with interests? What do they want from the PCs, what might the PCs want from them, where do they conflict, where might they compromise?
But again, keep in mind that while the PCs might have to put up with any people you create for the scene or two where it's the most important to those created people, you're not making people that your PCs must interact with. Let your PCs make up their minds about who they find interesting.
And hey, if they end up fostering a bitter rivalry (but in the good way) with some of the people in all those six arms of a criminal organization but they wind up in the dirt before all's said and done, the operator behind the cult behind everything has already raised one useful pawn from the dead. There can be room for more.
Hiding Merasmus
So, if your one PC who's a pupil of Merasmus were the main character in a story, then of course Merasmus would show up in act 1 scene 3, taunting the PC about how much greater they've become now and how they're now behind six criminal organizations and a cult.
But that PC isn't the main character of the story you want to tell. Everybody's got an equal shot. So Merasmus doesn't need to show up early.
This is different from the cult not showing up early. You might want to drop hints that the six arms of a criminal organization are motivated by more than just their own plans and schemes, and introduce cult ties early on.
If you want to do that, then you just need to make people in the cult, who interface with the criminal organization so Merasmus doesn't have to. Has he got a faithful lieutenant, a scheming lieutenant, an apathetic lieutenant? Multiple of the above? That can be fun, if the cult works with different crimers in different ways. And those people don't need any particular deep ties to Merasmus or your PC who's Merasmus's pupil. The cult is doing the will of their patron, not being Merasmus's errand-runners.
How Will You Know?
"If your other PCs don't have ties to anyone you're planning to sweep up in your campaign as deep as Merasmus's pupil has to Merasmus, don't worry about it too much for now. Keep Merasmus on the back burner and let your campaign run; by the time it reaches Merasmus, everyone else will have had ample opportunity to make ties in the world that are at least as meaningful to them."
And you're thinking, yeah, that sounds good, but is it really going to work out? And really, I don't know, I can't see the future. You'll be in a better position to know than I will, as long as you remember to keep up with your aftercare.
You might be familiar and have your own practices, you might not; if you want something simple to do every session I'd recommend looking into Roses, Thorns, and Buds or Stars and Wishes; I'd recommend the latter if you're running with strangers because there's less pressure to properly frame something negative. Get some reflection every session, find out what your players are interested in, and just keep that in mind as your plot keeps ticking along.
